# I'm trying to make bookmarks in Filezilla be availble on the desktop

Tags: shell, hyperlink, shortcut, bookmarks, filezilla

So far it only looks like the bookmarks you make become available inside Filezilla[1](http://filezilla-project.org) but I want to make them show up on the desktop like shortcut links.

Maybe a shell script would work? I am trying to find (arguments/parameters/options) what I can pass into filezilla via a command line but no luck so far here/google/etc. I'm checking out their documentation and wiki right now but, nothing seems to be mentioning how to do this.

I've done similar things with WINE and Editpadpro in Linux Mint in the past but I wish I could just find a way to get the parameters listed. It wouldn't be any different on OSX than it would anywhere else right? My friend needs it for that, but I think it could easily be ported to Linux and windows as well afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for command line parameters for FileZilla is [here](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)).

It looks like the closest you can get is to do:

> -c, --site
>   Connect to the given site from the Site Manager. Site has to be
>   given as complete path, with a slash
>   as separation character. Any slash or
>   backslash that is part of a segment
>   has to be escaped with a backslash.
>   Path has to be prefixed with 0 for
>   user defined entries or 1 for default
>   entries. Site path may not contain
>   double quotation marks. Example:
>   0/foo/bar/sl/ash connects to the user
>   site sl/ash in the site directory
>   foo/bar Start with Site Manager
>   opened. May not be used together with
>   -s nor with URL parameter. May not be used together with -c nor with URL
>   parameter.----